# Super capacitor as a battery replacement; lead-acid battery vs capacitor bank risks

Tags: batteries, supercapacitor

I'm considering replacing the lead-acid starting batteries on my boat with something like [this](https://www.maxwell.com/images/documents/ESM_Manual_Install_4_15.pdf), a 500 F @ 16 V starting battery module.

I understand the high-current risks associated with capacitors vs batteries. I had an older 12 V, 8 D battery explode on the boat. My guess is that it was off gassing due to age and condition and the gas ignited.

I have seen what happens when a lead-acid battery explodes, and the gas/acid is bad. What kind of gases/explosion/fire can I expect when something goes wrong with a capacitor?

Comment: so you your boat has no running lights or fixed radio? this is not a battery replacement

Comment: What about a hybrid? I think you should combine a capacitor with enough current to start the engine with low cost lithium ion cells.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty much the same, the explosion is faster because as soon as there is an internal short all the energy in the capacitor is dissipated into heat almost instantly. As far as gasses go, it depends on the electrolyte, and usually it's hydrogen. If the dielectric starts on fire, the smoke could be toxic.

Capacitors don't have near the storage capacity that batteries have and most capacitors leak current faster than batteries.

Comment: Storage capacity is not relevant since all I need to do is start the engine. Charge time from dead to full is 15 or 30 minutes depending on model @ 25 Amps. So If my boat is at the dock for a month and I decide to leave I 30 minutes for engine checks and all the other "pre-flight" checks I don't see as a problem. Once Boating maintain the capacitors "charge" should be un-noticeable power draw.

Comment: 8D battery is 130lb of lead that needs replacing every 5 years, ESM Capacitor is 20lb and should never need replacing. In the event of an capacitor explosion its less mass, so less risk overall?

Comment: @SBTech storage capacity matters a lot if your engine doesn't start first time, every time.  500F isn't a lot, and if your engine is cold or damp and doesn't want to start, you could be left dead in the water with no way to start the engine.

Answer (score 0):

So you break down at sea; what about emergency communications? Not very well thought out I think; batteries are your safety valve.

Enhancing starting an engine with a super cap is a good idea, but a super cap on its own won't do very well; it's just 1 A, 1 F at the chosen voltage. A 500 F super cap bank will last about 500 s provided you only draw 1 A, but starting an engine is like a short circuit, so just turn the motor over using 500 A for 1 s, then let the battery take over.

I would keep the battery and have super caps as well to get the best of both worlds, and live to tell the tale.